# Shopping cart DB not showing number of Individual Items Ordered

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a shopping cart model, I've created the Order Model, OrderItem model and Also the Item model. Although I find it difficult to link the order it model to the order in the API view.

here's the Model

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey("Pizza", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name



class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
//The viewset

class OrderViewSet(viewsets.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # permission_classes = [IsPostOrIsAuthenticated,]

    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
```

Currently, I cant display the amount attribute of the order item in my API, It just shows the id and Also the link to the individual orderitem in an order

Answer (score 0):

I think for cart you can use external fields on relations between Order and Pizza. Documentation about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Your models looks like:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, through='OrderItem')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Pizza', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

Example, how you can get dict of items amount in order:

```
order = Order.objects.filter('-created_at').first() // get last order
cart = {item.pk: item.amount for item in order.items}
```